# Matplotlib animation suppresses error message in a jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I want to debug code that uses matplotlib's `FuncAnimation` to animate a plot in a jupyter notebook.

However, I noticed that error messages are not passed on in the update function. For example, the code below explicitly raises an error, but its message never shows up in the output. The run simply stops.

My question is, how do I redirect the error stream so I can debug my (more complicated) code?

```
%matplotlib nbagg

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


def get_image():
    return np.random.random((20, 20))


def updatefig(*args):
    """Update and return image."""

    raise NameError() # <-- Error does not show!

    im.set_array(get_image())
    return im,


fig = plt.figure()
im = plt.imshow(get_image(), animated=True)

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, interval=20.0, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The problem is more that there is not standard output for interactive functions. E.g. if you replace `raise NameError()` by `print("hello")`, you wouldn't see that printed either. This is to say it has nothing to do with errors.

Comment: Just a crazy idea: Why don't you do the debugging running the code as script outside of Jupyter where you have usual standard output available?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Good idea, that's probably the way to go.

Comment: Still, it would be nice to have feedback weather the update function is simply running slow or the interactive session has crashed, and if it has how it crashed.